# How to search special characters using like operator in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got the requirement that I have to search special characters using the `like` operator in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Ex:

```
Name = sk'saintho

select * from table1 where name like 'sk'saintho'
```

For the above condition I am getting the error

> Incorrect syntax near 'saintho'.

Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

Ideas on this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use `like 'sk''saintho'`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server Management Studio you should see that the syntax formatting shows something is wrong with your query.

```
select * from table1 where name like 'sk'saintho'
```

The `sk` component will be red, as a literal string, and the `saintho` will be the regular black text. SQL doesn't understand that the `'` character is part of the string, and instead assumes that this is the end of the string.

Like is many other languages, the correct way to include a string termination symbol in a string is to include it twice. Using it twice tells the parser that you want to include the `'` inside the string instead of end the string.

```
select * from table1 where name like 'sk''saintho'
```

If you want to find all existing items that have the `'` character you can use the same pattern in a `like` statement

```
select * from table1 where name like '%''%'
```

The parser will interpret this as `like %'%` and you will find any rows where the name contains a `'`.

Comment: thanks kirk , i am using like operator in dynamic sql so if i add one single quote then for other conditions like normal name the like operator will fail. so my requirement is even though i am passing special charecters we should not include any additional quotes for like operator